# Cannot create Symlink via adb

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, adb, samsung-galaxy-tab-7.7

I try to create a symlink for a folder using adb. This is my attempt:

```
ln -s /storage/sdcard0/Android/media/com.amazon.mp3 /storage/sdcard0/mp3amazon
```

My device is rooted and as you can see this is the internal SdCard. not the external, so there should be no file-system-issues.

But all I receive for that command is a

> ln: /storage/sdcard0/mp3amazon: Function not implemented

Answer (score 1):

Have to answer myself (though this isn't a solution).
Android 5.0 Lollipop uses "Fuse" as file system which does not support SymLinks

Comment: And if it would, still the underlying filesystem could be fat, that wouldn't allow it, depending on if the symlink would end up in a fat partition...

Comment: @StefanHegny I was expecting the good old "ext" for the internal file system.